# lowest common ancestor with scala fold?

Tags: scala, fold, least-common-ancestor

I've been given a question on interview of desribing a method of finding LCA on binary tree. I resp with my idea. After all interviewer said it can be done with scala fold function... but I don't know how, any ideas?

Comment: fold is a method of Traversables and doesn't have anything to do with binary trees, so your interviewer was mistaken or you misunderstood.

Comment: I guess what he/she meant was if you have a function `lca: (Node, Node) => Node` then you could find the lca of a bunch of them in `nodes: List[Node]` with `nodes.tail.fold(nodes.head)(lca)` or better, `nodes.reduce(lca)`

Comment: I believe the term is "*last* common ancestor."

Comment: If the question was "given two nodes in a binary tree, find their LCA" and you are given (or can find, e.g. through a parent reference) the walk from root (a sequence) for each of the two nodes, you can use a fold to find where the walks diverge.

Comment: I suppose there is an easy solution for that. It all depends from good representation of branches in tree. For sure it must be an array (each branch)... but what comes next?